# Ext JS - Sencha cmd app configuration files and theme

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs5

I'm using Ext JS and Sencha CMD and want to experiment with a few themes.

Also I have read that the theme for an app can be changed in `app.js`(using theme property) and `sencha.cfg`(using app.theme property) and then run sencha app build.

I would like to know,
Why are this configurations in two different files?
And Which is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 5, the correct way to specify your application's theme is via the `app.json` file, as described [in the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/core_concepts/theming.html#Using_a_Theme_in_an_Application).

The `sencha.cfg` method also works, but is there to support migration from older versions of ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

Both are corrects ways to define the theme. However, it's better to have the theme defined in app.json. You'll anyway have a theme default defined in sencha.cfg -

```
app.theme=ext-theme-classic
```

What you define in app.json as

```
"theme": "my-theme"
```

will override what is defined in sencha.cfg

Refer the doc for clarity - http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/microloader.html